# How to add right value y-axis to Amcharts Column and Line mix?

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I am trying to display an y-axis to right of my charts : Here's [thelink](http://jsfiddle.net/LeTaulier/NB87h/)!

I would like the y-axis to display in link with the "expensises" value and with a different scale that the right one. For example from 40 to 80.

Thanks!

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
    "type": "serial",
    "theme": "chalk",
    "pathToImages": "/lib/3/images/",
    "autoMargins": false,
    "marginLeft":30,
    "marginRight":8,
    "marginTop":10,
    "marginBottom":26,

    "dataProvider": [{
        "year": 2009,
        "income": 23.5,
        "expenses": 58.1
    }, {
        "year": 2010,
        "income": 26.2,
        "expenses": 52.8
    }, {
        "year": 2011,
        "income": 30.1,
        "expenses": 53.9
    }, {
        "year": 2012,
        "income": 29.5,
        "expenses": 55.1
    }, {
        "year": 2013,
        "income": 30.6,
        "expenses": 47.2,
        "dashLengthLine": 5
    }, {
        "year": 2014,
        "income": 34.1,
        "expenses": 49.9,
        "dashLengthColumn": 5,
        "alpha": 0.2,
        "additional": "(projection)"
    }],
    "valueAxes": [{
        "axisAlpha": 0,
        "position": "left"
    }],
    "startDuration": 1,
    "graphs": [{
        "alphaField": "alpha",
        "balloonText": "<span style='font-size:13px;'>[[title]] in [[category]]:<b>[[value]]</b> [[additional]]</span>",
        "dashLengthField": "dashLengthColumn",
        "fillAlphas": 1,
        "title": "Income",
        "type": "column",
        "valueField": "income"
    }, {
        "balloonText": "<span style='font-size:13px;'>[[title]] in [[category]]:<b>[[value]]</b> [[additional]]</span>",
        "bullet": "round",
        "dashLengthField": "dashLengthLine",
        "lineThickness": 3,
        "bulletSize": 7,
        "bulletBorderAlpha": 1,
        "bulletColor": "#FFFFFF",
        "useLineColorForBulletBorder": true,
        "bulletBorderThickness": 3,
        "fillAlphas": 0,
        "lineAlpha": 1,
        "title": "Expenses",
        "valueField": "expenses"
    }],
    "categoryField": "year",
    "categoryAxis": {
        "gridPosition": "start",
        "axisAlpha":0,
        "tickLength":0
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a new axis.
I add three axis in this sample because I have three columns in the CSV file it reads but it should work with any amount of axises. It adds an axis to the left, next one to the right, and so on :

```
 axises[n] = new amCharts.ValueAxis();
            axises[n].title = titles[n];
            if ( n % 2 == 1 )
                {axises[n].position = "right";}
            chart.addValueAxis(axises[n]);
```